# Algebraic Geometry and Maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

I am solving the following problem but couldn't figure out a strategy to solve:

Does $(x^3-17, y^2)$ generate maximal ideals in the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ where $I$ is the principal ideal generated by the polynomial $y^2+x^3-17$? What is a common strategy to solve this kind of problems?

One thing that I noticed was the following: If we solve $x^3-17=0$ and $y^2=0$ then the solutions to these equation when plugged in the equation $y^2+x^3-17$ yields 0. I am not sure what it means. Does that mean that $I$ is indeed the whole ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: Maximal ideals of $R$ look like $(x-\root 3\of{17},y)$ and such. Get one of those for all solutions $(x,y)$ of $y^2+x^3-17=0$.

Comment: Would $x$ just be $17^{1/3}$ and $y$ be $0$?

Comment: This is over $\Bbb{C}$! For any $y$ there are three choices for $x$. Infinitely many solutions - infinitely many maximal ideals.

Comment: But yeah, your $J=(x^3-17,y^2)$ is contained in those three maximal ideals $m_k=(y,x-\root3\of{17}\omega^k)$, $k=0,1,2,$ with $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Do you see that $J\subset m_k, k=0,1,2$? And that all the $m_k$ are maximal?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: What would getting 1 by solving the quations and plugging it mean? Because I have another set $(x-1, y-4)$ and if we solve for $x$ and $y$ and plug it in the equation we get 1. And the book says that it generated maximal ideal. Thus, does it mean it is not sufficient to get a 1 after solving?

Comment: How did you get $1$? If $x=1, y=4$, then $y^2+x^3-17=4^2+1^3-17=0$, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Aha! It is 0 indeed. I am typing up one of my assignments where $0$ is labelled as $1$. Hence the mixup. I apologize for the confusion. However, my question still holds as to does it mean it is the whole ring? $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? (Sorry again for the confusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $(y^2+x^3-17)\subset (y^2,x^3-17)$. Therefore, the quotient of the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ by the ideal, generated by $(y^2,x^3-17)$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2,x^3-17)$. All I am using here is that for any ring $A$ and ideals $I\subset J$, we have an isomorphism $(A/I)/(J/I)\simeq A/J$. So the question boils down to determining if $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2,x^3-17)$ is a field. It is obviously not. So the answer is "no".

Comment: We can say that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2,x^3-17)$ is not a field because both $y^2,x^3-17$ are reducible?

Comment: That's right. In particular we have $\bar y\neq 0$ and $\bar y^2=0$ in this ring, which is not possible in a field.